# Probability of getting 4 hearts in 5 cards from very big deck of cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that when randomly picking $5$ cards from a deck, you'll get $4$ hearts. Assume that number of cards in a deck is very big.

Comment: Are 1/4 of the cards hearts?

Comment: What have you tried?  When you say very big, you are saying the proportion of hearts does not change when you draw some cards.  You need the proportion of hearts in the deck, presumably $1/4$.  Now use the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

In a real deck it is $\frac{\binom{13}{5}+39\binom{13}{4}}{\binom{52}5}$.

This is the total number of ways to pick four or five hearts, divided by the total number of ways to pick five cards.

As the number of cards increases, the effect of earlier choices on later ones will be less and less. If you pick a heart first, then the chance of picking another heart less will be slightly less than $1/4$, but in the limit the chance of getting a heart will tend to $1/4$ irrespective of what the previous cards were. So the limiting probability is $(\frac 14)^5+5\times(\frac14)^4\times\frac34$.